# Need help exporting rendered animation in video format

Tags: rendering, export

I am using blender to create a YouTube intro. I am using blender 2.77a and have already rendered my 600 frame animation. How can I export my rendered animation in a video format so I can add it to my YouTube videos

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose video format in *Output* settings and then render *Animation*. You have variety of options for video such as bitrate, codec etc.

[image: settings]

Comment: youtube's got several explainers for what they expect, but their conversion tools are pretty smart.